# Migrating an on-topic question if it does not generate an answer

Tags: discussion, policy, cross-posting

If we asked a question which was seen as on-topic (and maybe even upvoted) and it hung around on the site for a while, but did not generate an answer. Can we migrate the question to another site where it remains in scope? Or should I just cross-post and double-link?

As a concrete example, I asked a question about crypto-currency on Jun 28:

[Bitcoin and preventing double spending in decentralized digital currencies](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7145/1037)

It generated a answer-comment but not quiet an answer, some upvotes, and otherwise has sat idly on cstheory. Since that time, however, a new SE site sprung up:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Where this question would remain in scope. Does it make sense to migrate the question if the OP (in this case me) agrees? Or would that be bad-practice?

Answer (score 7):

Migrating means closing as off-topic for this site. Also someone may answer the question in future so I think it shouldn't be done in such cases.

On the other hand, no one is preventing you from posting it by yourself on other sites (cross-post) after a reasonable time has passed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that dubbing off-topic and migrating were inherently linked. I will stick to the cross-posting then.